# Dynamically change control color when hovered without changing back when hovering childs

Tags: c#, winforms, events, controls, panel

I have a application that talks to the Database-API of a game and displays information about certain items. One part of the UI looks like this:

[image: Default UI]

For the grey boxes I have created a control called 'ItemPreviewControl', which each show information about one specific found Item. I want the control to become red when hovered and return to gray when the mouse leaves the control. For this I have used the MouseEnter- and MouseLeave-Events of the ItemPreviewControl, and as you can see here it also works:

[image: UI when hovered]

Here's the code I used:

```
private Color mainColor_MouseEnterLeave;

private void ItemPreviewControl_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mainColor_MouseEnterLeave = this.BackColor;
    this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 0);
}

private void ItemPreviewControl_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackColor = mainColor_MouseEnterLeave;
}
```

Now the problem I have is the following: My 'ItemPreviewControl' also changes back to gray when I hovor above one of its child elemenets, so e.g. when I hover above the textboxes **inside** the control. **But I want the control to stay red until I leave the actual control. Do you have any ideas of how to implement this?**

The UI is a Windows Forms App. The UI as well as all the Backend-Libraries are in .NET Core 3.1.

Thank you for reading.

**Edit: Solution for my problem:**
It turns out I had to check whether the Mouse is still inside the UserControl's bounds. If yes, cancel the MouseLeave-Method with a return, and otherwise continue the method. Here's my updated code:

```
private void ItemPreviewControl_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 0);
}

private void ItemPreviewControl_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ClientRectangle.Contains(this.PointToClient(MousePosition)))
        return;

    this.BackColor = Color.FromName("Gray");
}
```

Comment: In `MouseLeave`, you can check whether the MousePosition is still inside the UserControl's bounds. e.g., `if (this.ClientRectangle.Contains(this.PointToClient(MousePosition))) return;`. Are you sure you want handle just MouseEnter/MouseLeave? Maybe use Enter/Leave instead, so a User can also Tab into the UCs and have the same *effect*.

Comment: Btw, careful with the Color assignment in `MouseEnter`, since also that event is called multiple times, when the Pointer leaves the bounds of child Controls insides the UC. You probably want to track the mouse movements.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for your help! It worked! And I also have noticed that the MouseEnter gets called multiple times and because it overrides my variable 'mainColor_MouseEnterLeave' to "Red", which means I couldn't change it back to gray. By removing the variable I made it work perfectly fine. I updated my question with the current working code. Feel free to take a look into it. Unfortunately the Enter/Leave-Event don't get called when I hover with my mouse above the controls, so I stayed with the MouseEnter/MouseLeave.

Comment: Yes, you can :) In `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseLeave`, just call `OnEnter` and `OnLeave` (btw, in UserControls and Custom Controls, you should override the methods, not subscribe to the events). e.g., `protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e) {
base.OnMouseEnter(e); this.OnEnter(e); }` and in `OnEnter`: `protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e) { this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(192, 0, 0); base.OnEnter(e); }`. The same for `OnMouseLeave`. Btw2, you could add a Field to the UC to store the UC BackColor, so you don't need to hard-code: `this.BackColor = Color.FromName("Gray");`

Comment: Ok I got it with the Events so far. But I can't make the Field in the UC work, although I followed multiple tutorials on the internet.

Comment: Maybe just put change in `MouseHover`?